# Python scipy modules can't be imported with macports install

Tags: python, osx-lion, scipy, macports

I've just reinstalled OSX Lion and decided to use macports to get an updated python, plus numpy, scipy, matplotlib, ipython, etc. After some fuss everything looks installed correctly in the /opt/ folder, and numpy, matplotlib, and ipython are running correctly, but when I try to import modules in scipy I get a failure that seems to go back to the sparse module:

```
>>> import scipy.sparse as sparse
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/__init__.py", line 175, in <module>
from csr import *
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/csr.py", line 12, in <module>
from sparsetools import csr_tocsc, csr_tobsr, csr_count_blocks, \
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/sparsetools/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
from csr import *
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/sparsetools/csr.py", line 25, in <module>
_csr = swig_import_helper()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/sparsetools/csr.py", line 21, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_csr', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: dlopen(/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/sparsetools/_csr.so, 2): Symbol not found: ___emutls_get_address
  Referenced from: /opt/local/lib/gcc45/libstdc++.6.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /opt/local/lib/gcc45/libstdc++.6.dylib
```

Import scipy.stats or such things ends up in the same place. I've googled a bunch and tried fixing various PATH variables (in the python interpreter and out), as well as hiding the default python install(s? what's the difference between the one in the main Library and the one in /usr/?) and reinstalling scipy but that's done nothing.

I'm not very familiar or comfortable with this stuff - I was working with the EPD before I wiped and reinstalled, but had run into problems getting new packages to recognize that. I use python for scientific stuff, hence not really understanding its guts! So answers assuming I barely understand what a PATH variable is are much appreciated.

So 
(a) Is there an easy way to fix whatever is going on above?
(b) Should I delete some stuff and start from scratch? 
(c) Is there a non-painful way to get scipy, numpy, matplotlib, and ipython (plus the things it needs for the qtconsole and the html notebook), AND be able to install new packages in the right place? Should I go back to EPD if possible (their academic email thing failed for me, so I moved on)?

Comment: My first guess is you've ended up compiling most of your code with one toolchain, but some of it with another. I'm assuming to get /opt/local/lib/gcc45 you did a "port install gcc45". But did you then do anything to trick MacPorts or other things into using that in place of the system compiler? If so, what? (And why?) If not, try "port deactivate gcc45" and then clean-rebuild python, scipy, etc.

Comment: I did everything in a row without doing anything fancy, so I'm really perplexed as to how it went wrong! Er, apparently return sends a comment. More in a sec.

Comment: I basically did this: http://sublimated.wordpress.com/2009/01/20/how-to-install-matplotlib-and-scipy-using-macports/, except *maybe* I didn't do python_select at the right point. Could that have effed it up?

Curiously, when I try to deactivate, it won't let me because I have ports that depend on it - notably scipy. But then, I have been messing around with things since then - I hadn't touched gcc_select or anything until after I found out scipy didn't work. I'll uninstall stuff and try again.

Comment: Maybe doing pythong_select at the wrong point could break things. But reading that blog, I don't see any recommendation to install gcc45, so you obviously have done more than recommended there, and I still suspect your problem is with the wrong gcc, not the wrong Python. So again, deactivate it and rebuild everything.

Comment: PS, I've found it much easier to just use Apple's python 2.7 and pip to install Python modules. (Of course you do need to get a Fortran compiler somewhere—MacPorts or otherwise. And you have to rebuild numpy after the Fortran installer is there, which is a bit of an annoyance.) Once upon a time, Apple's Python was two major versions behind, came with incomplete headers, etc., so all the recommendations to avoid it like the plague made sense, but none of that is true anymore.

Comment: I definitely didn't explicitly install gcc45 - I think when I installed python (or maybe numpy), it decided that was a dependency and downloaded it automatically. Still, I think starting from scratch is probably the best option. Thanks!

ETA: Re: apple's version being improved - yeah, I noticed that the python that came with this reinstall of Lion is much more up to date than the last time I looked at it (when it was 1.6 or something?)

Comment: My guess is that numpy needed some fortran, and MacPorts decided installing gcc45 made more sense than installing the apple-gcc-42 gfortran. Anyway, whatever happened, that's another good reason not to use MacPorts for this. As for Apple's Python: they were never _that_ far out of date, and they've been fine since 10.6. MacPorts is only better if you having 2.7.2 instead of 2.7.1 is more important to you than, say, having a setuptools that's actually configured right.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the  [Enthought Python Free distribution](http://www.enthought.com/products/epd_free.php), its free and generally is an easy install, and comes with Numpy, Scipy, matplotlib etc.

Comment: That's what I had before, but I couldn't get other packages to install with that version. I've read a little more since then, though, so that might not be a problem anymore.

Comment: I've never had issues with EPD Free, so I would try that one again.

Comment: I *have* had plenty of issues with Macports however.